# Application search form

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

I have a search form in my application. When I search, it takes too much time to retrieve and display data, so I need to optimize this code.

[image: image of search form of my application]

```
public void search_thread()
{
    Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
    sw.Start();



    string sqlcmd = "select en.eventname,q.Q,q.QLevel,q.QUsed,q.QType,q.QAlt,q.QStatus,q.QTag ,m.MediaName,m.MediaPath,m.MediaTag,m.MediaType,O.*,c.Cat1,c.Cat2,c.CatTags,c.SubCat1,c.SubCat2 from tblQ q Inner join tblMediaType  m ON q.QRefNo =M.QRefNo  Inner Join tblOptions  o On  Q.QRefNo =o.QRefNo  Inner Join tblCategories c On Q.QRefNo = c.QRefNo Inner Join tbleventname en On Q.QRefNo = en.QRefNo";

    int flag_checked = 0;

    if (t_search.Text.Trim() != "")
    {
        sqlcmd = sqlcmd + " where (q.Qalt  like N'%" + t_search.Text.Trim() + "%' or o.oAlt1  like N'%" + t_search.Text.Trim() + "%' or o.oAlt2 like N'%" + t_search.Text.Trim() + "%' or o.oAlt3 like N'%" + t_search.Text.Trim() + "%' or o.oAlt4 like N'%" + t_search.Text.Trim() + "%' or o.oAlt5 like N'%" + t_search.Text.Trim() + "%' or O.oAlt6 = N'%" + t_search.Text.Trim() + "%' or o.oAlt7 like N'%" + t_search.Text.Trim() + "%' or o.oAlt8 like N'%" + t_search.Text.Trim() + "%' or o.oAlt9 like N'%" + t_search.Text.Trim() + "%' or o.oAlt10 like N'%" + t_search.Text.Trim() + "%' or o.oAlt11 like N'%" + t_search.Text.Trim() + "%' or o.oAlt12 like N'%" + t_search.Text.Trim() + "%' or q.Q like '%" + t_search.Text.Trim() + "%' or o.o1 like  '%" + t_search.Text.Trim() + "%' or o.o2 like '%" + t_search.Text.Trim() + "%' or o.o3 like '%" + t_search.Text.Trim() + "%' or o.o4 like '%" + t_search.Text.Trim() + "%' or o.o5 like '%" + t_search.Text.Trim() + "%' or o.o6  like '%" + t_search.Text.Trim() + "%' or o.o7  like '%" + t_search.Text.Trim() + "%' or o.o8  like '%" + t_search.Text.Trim() + "%' or o.o9  like '%" + t_search.Text.Trim() + "%'  or o.o10  like '%" + t_search.Text + "%' or o.o11  like '%" + t_search.Text.Trim() + "%' or o.o12  like '%" + t_search.Text.Trim() + "%' or o.CorrectAns  like '%" + t_search.Text.Trim() + "%' )";
        flag_checked = 1;

        if (r_Excludestack.Checked == true)
        {
            if (con.State != ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                if (con.State != ConnectionState.Open){con.Open();}
            }
            SqlCommand smc = new SqlCommand("select distinct count(qrefno) from tblStackData", con);
            int qrefnocnt = Convert.ToInt32(smc.ExecuteScalar());

            string scmd = "select  qrefno from tblStackData";
            string[] temp_qref_array = new string[qrefnocnt];
            smc = new SqlCommand(scmd, con);
            int i = 0;
            if (dr != null)
            {
                if (dr.IsClosed)
                {
                    dr = smc.ExecuteReader();
                }
                else
                {
                    dr.Close();
                    dr = smc.ExecuteReader();
                }
            }
            else
                dr = smc.ExecuteReader();


            while (dr.Read())
                temp_qref_array[i++] = dr["qrefno"].ToString();
            con.Close();
            scmd = "";
            for (i = 0; i < temp_qref_array.Length - 1; i++)
            {
                scmd = scmd + "'" + temp_qref_array[i] + "',";
            }
            scmd = scmd + "'" + temp_qref_array[i] + "'";

            sqlcmd = sqlcmd + " and Q.qrefNo Not IN (" + scmd + ")";

        }

        if (r_search4mstack.Checked == true)
        {


            if (con.State != ConnectionState.Open) {  if (con.State != ConnectionState.Open){con.Open();}}
            SqlCommand smc = new SqlCommand("select distinct count(qrefno) from tblStackData", con);
            int qrefnocnt = Convert.ToInt32(smc.ExecuteScalar());

            string scmd = "select  qrefno from tblStackData";
            string[] temp_qref_array = new string[qrefnocnt];
            smc = new SqlCommand(scmd, con);
            int i = 0;
            if (dr != null)
            {
                if (dr.IsClosed)
                {
                    dr = smc.ExecuteReader();
                }
                else
                {
                    dr.Close();
                    dr = smc.ExecuteReader();
                }
            }
            else
                dr = smc.ExecuteReader();

            while (dr.Read())
                temp_qref_array[i++] = dr["qrefno"].ToString();
            con.Close();
            scmd = "";
            for (i = 0; i < temp_qref_array.Length - 1; i++)
            {
                scmd = scmd + "'" + temp_qref_array[i] + "',";
            }
            scmd = scmd + "'" + temp_qref_array[i] + "'";



            sqlcmd = sqlcmd + " and Q.qrefNo  IN (" + scmd + ")";
        }

        if (r_searchnotused.Checked == true)
        {
            if (con.State != ConnectionState.Open){ if (con.State != ConnectionState.Open){con.Open();}}
            SqlCommand smc = new SqlCommand("select distinct count(qrefno) from tblQ where Qused Not In ('','null','0')", con);
            int qrefnocnt = Convert.ToInt32(smc.ExecuteScalar());

            string scmd = "select  qrefno from  tblQ where Qused Not In ('','null','0')";
            string[] temp_qref_array = new string[qrefnocnt];
            smc = new SqlCommand(scmd, con);
            int i = 0;
            if (dr != null)
            {
                if (dr.IsClosed)
                {
                    dr = smc.ExecuteReader();
                }
                else
                {
                    dr.Close();
                    dr = smc.ExecuteReader();
                }
            }
            else
                dr = smc.ExecuteReader();

            while (  dr.Read())
                temp_qref_array[i++] = dr["qrefno"].ToString();
            con.Close();
            scmd = "";

            for (i = 0; i < temp_qref_array.Length - 1; i++)
            {
                scmd = scmd + "'" + temp_qref_array[i] + "',";
            }

            scmd = scmd + "'" + temp_qref_array[i] + "'";

            sqlcmd = sqlcmd + " and Q.qrefNo Not IN (" + scmd + ")";
        }

        if (r_stackedbutnotused.Checked == true)
        {
            if (con.State != ConnectionState.Open){if (con.State != ConnectionState.Open){con.Open();}}
            SqlCommand smc = new SqlCommand("select distinct count(qrefno) from tblQ where Qused  In ('','null','0')", con);
            int qrefnocnt = Convert.ToInt32(smc.ExecuteScalar());

            string scmd = "select  qrefno from  tblQ where Qused  In ('','null','0')";
            string[] temp_qref_array = new string[qrefnocnt];
            smc = new SqlCommand(scmd, con);
            int i = 0;
            if (dr != null)
            {
                if (dr.IsClosed)
                {
                    dr = smc.ExecuteReader();
                }
                else
                {
                    dr.Close();
                    dr = smc.ExecuteReader();
                }
            }
            else
                dr = smc.ExecuteReader();

            while (dr.Read())
                temp_qref_array[i++] = dr["qrefno"].ToString();
            dr.Close();
            scmd = "";
            for (i = 0; i < temp_qref_array.Length - 1; i++)
            {
                scmd = scmd + "'" + temp_qref_array[i] + "',";
            }
            scmd = scmd + "'" + temp_qref_array[i] + "'";


            smc = new SqlCommand("select distinct count(qrefno)  from tblStackData where qrefno  In(" + scmd + ")", con);
            qrefnocnt = Convert.ToInt32(smc.ExecuteScalar());


            scmd = "select  qrefno from tblStackData where qrefno  In(" + scmd + ")";
            temp_qref_array = new string[qrefnocnt];
            smc = new SqlCommand(scmd, con);
            i = 0;
            try
            {
                dr = smc.ExecuteReader();
                while (dr.Read())
                    temp_qref_array[i++] = dr["qrefno"].ToString();
                con.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception h)
            {

            }

            scmd = "";
            if (temp_qref_array.Length != 0)
            {
                for (i = 0; i < temp_qref_array.Length - 1; i++)
                {
                    scmd = scmd + "'" + temp_qref_array[i] + "',";
                }
                scmd = scmd + "'" + temp_qref_array[i] + "'";
                sqlcmd = sqlcmd + " and Q.qrefNo  IN (" + scmd + ")";
            }

        }
    }

    if (T_refno.Text.Trim() != "")
    {
        if (flag_checked == 0)
        {
            flag_checked = 1;
            sqlcmd = sqlcmd + " where O.QrefNo like '%" + T_refno.Text.Trim() + "%' ";
        }
        else
        {
            sqlcmd = sqlcmd + " and O.QrefNo like '%" + T_refno.Text.Trim() + "%' ";
        }
    }


 //   string en = null;
  //  label6.Invoke(new Action(() => en = c_eventname.Text));
    if ( c_eventname.Text != null &&  c_eventname.Text.Trim() != "")
    {
        if (flag_checked == 0)
        {
            flag_checked = 1;
            sqlcmd = sqlcmd + " where en.eventname = '" +  c_eventname.Text + "' ";
        }
        else
        {
            sqlcmd = sqlcmd + " and en.eventname = '" +  c_eventname.Text + "' ";
        }
    }

  //  label6.Invoke(new Action(() => en = c_qtype.Text));
    if ( c_qtype.Text != null &&  c_qtype.Text.ToString().Trim() != "")
    {
        if (flag_checked == 0)
        {
            flag_checked = 1;
            sqlcmd = sqlcmd + " where Q.QType = '" +  c_qtype.Text + "' ";
        }
        else
        {
            sqlcmd = sqlcmd + " and Q.QType = '" + c_qtype.Text + "' ";
        }
    }
  //  label6.Invoke(new Action(() => en = c_qtype.Text));
    if ( c_level.Text != null && c_level.Text!= "")
    {
        if (flag_checked == 0)
        {
            flag_checked = 1;
            sqlcmd = sqlcmd + " where Q.QLevel = " + c_level.Text;
        }
        else
        {
            sqlcmd = sqlcmd + " and Q.QLevel = " + c_level.Text;
        }
    }

 //   label6.Invoke(new Action(() => en = c_qtype.Text));
//    Console.WriteLine("Qtype " +  C_category.Text);
    if ( C_category.Text != null &&  C_category.Text != "")
    {
        if (flag_checked == 0)
        {
            flag_checked = 1;
            sqlcmd = sqlcmd + " where  C.Cat1 = '" + C_category.Text + "'";
        }
        else
        {
            sqlcmd = sqlcmd + " and  C.Cat1 = '" +  C_category.Text + "'";
        }

    }
   // label6.Invoke(new Action(() => en =  .Text));
    if ( c_subcategory.Text != null &&  c_subcategory.Text.Trim() != "")
    {
        if (flag_checked == 0)
        {
            flag_checked = 1;
            sqlcmd = sqlcmd + " where  C.subCat1 = '" +  c_subcategory.Text + "'";
        }
        else
        {
            sqlcmd = sqlcmd + " and  C.subCat1 = '" + c_subcategory.Text + "'";
        }
    }


    try
    {
        if (con.State != ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            if (con.State != ConnectionState.Open){con.Open();}
        }
        cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlcmd, con);

        if (dr != null) if (dr.IsClosed) { dr = cmd.ExecuteReader(); } else { dr.Close(); dr = cmd.ExecuteReader(); } else dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();

        while (dr.Read())
        {
            try
            {
                int f = 0;
                try
                {
                    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(dr["qrefno"].ToString(), dr["QType"].ToString(), dr["Qused"].ToString(), dr["CorrectAns"].ToString(), dr["Q"].ToString(), dr["o1"].ToString(), dr["o2"].ToString(), dr["o3"].ToString(), dr["o4"].ToString(), dr["o5"].ToString(), dr["o6"].ToString(), dr["o7"].ToString(), dr["o8"].ToString(), dr["o9"].ToString(), dr["o10"].ToString(), dr["o11"].ToString(), dr["o12"].ToString(), dr["MediaName"].ToString(), dr["MediaType"].ToString(), dr["cat1"].ToString());
                   // label6.Invoke(new Action(() => f = dataGridView1.Rows.Add(dr["qrefno"].ToString(), dr["QType"].ToString(), dr["Qused"].ToString(), dr["CorrectAns"].ToString(), dr["Q"].ToString(), dr["o1"].ToString(), dr["o2"].ToString(), dr["o3"].ToString(), dr["o4"].ToString(), dr["o5"].ToString(), dr["o6"].ToString(), dr["o7"].ToString(), dr["o8"].ToString(), dr["o9"].ToString(), dr["o10"].ToString(), dr["o11"].ToString(), dr["o12"].ToString(), dr["MediaName"].ToString(), dr["MediaType"].ToString(), dr["cat1"].ToString())));
                }
                catch ( System.InvalidOperationException exe)
                {
                    break;
                }
                if (dr["QUsed"].ToString() == "" || dr["QUsed"].ToString() == "0")
                {

                    //  dataGridView1.Rows[f].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
                }
                else
                {
                    dataGridView1.Rows[f].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;

                }

            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                dr.Close();

            }


        }
        con.Close();
        l_searchfound.Text = dataGridView1.Rows.Count.ToString();
      //  l_searchfound.Invoke(new Action(() => l_searchfound.Text = dataGridView1.Rows.Count + ""));
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("Task countUP2 took: " + sw.Elapsed.ToString());
    }
    catch (Exception e1)
    {
        con.Close();
        dr.Close();

    }
  // b_search.Enabled = true;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [ask] page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: To make life easier for reviewers, please add sufficient context to your question. The more you tell us about what your code does and what the purpose of doing that is, the easier it will be for reviewers to help you. See also [this meta question](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/1226/code-should-include-a-description-of-what-the-code-does)

Comment: This question has been cross-posted: http://superuser.com/q/888707/53590 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/29007994/486504

Comment: Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just would love to enter inside your `t_search` textbox something like

```
a'); DROP TABLE tblStackData; DROP TABLE tblOptions; DROP TABLE tblCategories;
```

deleting 3 tables of your database.

Do yourself a favour and use [parameterized queries](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17512230/2655508) to avoid [SQL injections](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/)

---

One shouldn't use string concatenation like

```
scmd = "";
for (i = 0; i < temp_qref_array.Length - 1; i++)
{
    scmd = scmd + "'" + temp_qref_array[i] + "',";
}
scmd = scmd + "'" + temp_qref_array[i] + "'";
```

in a loop. That's what the [`StringBuilder`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class is for.

leading to

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(1024);
for (i = 0; i < temp_qref_array.Length - 1; i++)
{
    sb.Append("'").Append(temp_qref_array[i]).Append("',");
}
sb.Append("'").Append(temp_qref_array[i]).Append("'");  

sqlcmd = sqlcmd + " and Q.qrefNo Not IN (" + sb.ToString() + ")";
```

or much better make `sqlcmd` also a `StringBuilder` resulting in

```
sqlcmd.Append(" and Q.qrefNo Not IN (")
for (i = 0; i < temp_qref_array.Length - 1; i++)
{
    sqlcmd.Append("'").Append(temp_qref_array[i]).Append("',");
}
sqlcmd.Append("'").Append(temp_qref_array[i]).Append("')")
```

but we still can do better, by using [`String.Join()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.join%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) like @Simon André Forsberg suggested like

```
sqlcmd.Append(" and Q.qrefNo Not IN ('")
      .Append(String.Join("','" , temp_qref_array))
      .Append("'");
```

---

You have the following patter very often

```
if (dr != null)
{
    if (dr.IsClosed)
    {
        dr = smc.ExecuteReader();
    }
    else
    {
        dr.Close();
        dr = smc.ExecuteReader();
    }
}
else
    dr = smc.ExecuteReader();
```

which can be simplified to

```
if (dr != null && !dr.IsClosed)
{
   dr.Close();
}
dr = smc.ExecuteReader();
```

---

Here you are calling `t_search.Text.Trim()` over and over again (I can't count how often).

```
if (t_search.Text.Trim() != "")
{
    sqlcmd = sqlcmd + " where (q.Qalt  like N'%" + t_search.Text.Trim() + "%' or o.oAlt1  like N'%" + t_search.Text.Trim() + "%' or o.oAlt2 like N'%" + t_search.Text.Trim() + "%' or o.oAlt3 like N'%" + t_search.Text.Trim() + "%' or o.oAlt4 like N'%" + t_search.Text.Trim() + "%' or o.oAlt5 like N'%" + t_search.Text.Trim() + "%' or O.oAlt6 = N'%" + t_search.Text.Trim() + "%' or o.oAlt7 like N'%" + t_search.Text.Trim() + "%' or o.oAlt8 like N'%" + t_search.Text.Trim() + "%' or o.oAlt9 like N'%" + t_search.Text.Trim() + "%' or o.oAlt10 like N'%" + t_search.Text.Trim() + "%' or o.oAlt11 like N'%" + t_search.Text.Trim() + "%' or o.oAlt12 like N'%" + t_search.Text.Trim() + "%' or q.Q like '%" + t_search.Text.Trim() + "%' or o.o1 like  '%" + t_search.Text.Trim() + "%' or o.o2 like '%" + t_search.Text.Trim() + "%' or o.o3 like '%" + t_search.Text.Trim() + "%' or o.o4 like '%" + t_search.Text.Trim() + "%' or o.o5 like '%" + t_search.Text.Trim() + "%' or o.o6  like '%" + t_search.Text.Trim() + "%' or o.o7  like '%" + t_search.Text.Trim() + "%' or o.o8  like '%" + t_search.Text.Trim() + "%' or o.o9  like '%" + t_search.Text.Trim() + "%'  or o.o10  like '%" + t_search.Text + "%' or o.o11  like '%" + t_search.Text.Trim() + "%' or o.o12  like '%" + t_search.Text.Trim() + "%' or o.CorrectAns  like '%" + t_search.Text.Trim() + "%' )";
    flag_checked = 1;
```

better store the returned value in a variable like (asuming `sqlcmd` now is a `StringBuilder`)

```
String searchText = t_search.Text.Trim();  
if (searchText.Length > 0)
{
    sqlcmd.Append(" where (q.Qalt  like N'%")
          .Append(searchText)
          .Append("%' or o.oAlt1  like N'%")
          .Append(searchText)
          .Append("%' or o.oAlt2 like N'%")
          .Append(searchText)
          .Append("%' or o.oAlt3 like N'%")
          .Append(searchText)  

           ... and so on
```

---

Expressions like `if (r_Excludestack.Checked == true)` can be simplified to `if (r_Excludestack.Checked)`.

---

You really should split this **god method** into multiple methods. Like the part of

```
if (r_Excludestack.Checked)
{

}
```

should be extracted to a method which I name now `GetExcludeStackCondition()`

```
private string GetExcludeStackCondition()
{
    if (con.State != ConnectionState.Open)
    {
        con.Open();
    }

    SqlCommand smc = new SqlCommand("select distinct count(qrefno) from tblStackData", con);
    int qrefnocnt = Convert.ToInt32(smc.ExecuteScalar());

    smc = new SqlCommand("select qrefno from tblStackData", con);

    DataReader dr = smc.ExecuteReader();

    int i = 0;
    string[] temp_qref_array = new string[qrefnocnt];
    while (dr.Read())
    {
        temp_qref_array[i++] = dr["qrefno"].ToString();
    }
    con.Close();

    StringBuilder scmd = new StringBuilder(1024);
    scmd.Append(" and Q.qrefNo Not IN ('")
        .Append(String.Join("','" , temp_qref_array))
        .Append("'");

    return scmd.ToString();
}
```

and would be called like

```
if (r_Excludestack.Checked)
{
    sqlcmd.Append(GetExcludeStackCondition());
}
```

resulting in reducing the former method by a lot of code and making it more readable and easier to maintain.

Comment: Doesn't C# have some kind of String Join method? Seems perfect for that for-loop appending stuff.

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg good catch, updated answer

Answer (score 1):

you take the result from one query and then feed it into another:

instead you can nest them:

```
sqlcmd = sqlcmd + " and Q.qrefNo Not IN (select  qrefno from tblStackData)"
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for replying my question.
So according to above comments I have updated my code.
It improved some performance.

```
    public void search_thread()
    {
        Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
        sw.Start();


        StringBuilder sqlcmd = new StringBuilder();
        sqlcmd.Append("select en.eventname,q.Q,q.QLevel,q.QUsed,q.QType,q.QAlt,q.QStatus,q.QTag ,m.MediaName,m.MediaPath,m.MediaTag,m.MediaType,O.*,c.Cat1,c.Cat2,c.CatTags,c.SubCat1,c.SubCat2 from tblQ q Inner join tblMediaType  m ON q.QRefNo =M.QRefNo  Inner Join tblOptions  o On  Q.QRefNo =o.QRefNo  Inner Join tblCategories c On Q.QRefNo = c.QRefNo Inner Join tbleventname en On Q.QRefNo = en.QRefNo");

        int flag_checked = 0;

        String search_text = t_search.Text.Trim();


        if (search_text.Length > 0)
        {
            sqlcmd.Append(" where (q.Qalt  like N'%")
                  .Append(search_text)
                  .Append("%' or o.oAlt1  like N'%")
                  .Append(search_text)
                  .Append("%' or o.oAlt2 like N'%")
                  .Append(search_text)
                  .Append("%' or o.oAlt3 like N'%")
                  .Append(search_text)
                  .Append("%' or o.oAlt4 like N'%")
                  .Append(search_text)
                  .Append("%' or o.oAlt5 like N'%")
                  .Append(search_text)
                  .Append("%' or o.oAlt6 like N'%")
                  .Append(search_text)
                  .Append("%' or o.oAlt7 like N'%")
                  .Append(search_text)
                  .Append("%' or o.oAlt8 like N'%")
                  .Append(search_text)
                  .Append("%' or o.oAlt9 like N'%")
                  .Append(search_text)
                  .Append("%' or o.oAlt10 like N'%")
                  .Append(search_text)
                  .Append("%' or o.oAlt11 like N'%")
                  .Append(search_text)
                  .Append("%' or o.oAlt12 like N'%")
                  .Append(search_text)
                  .Append("%' or q.Q like '%")
                  .Append(search_text)
                  .Append("%' or o.o1 like '%")
                  .Append(search_text)
                  .Append("%' or o.o2 like '%")
                  .Append(search_text)
                  .Append("%' or o.o3 like '%")
                  .Append(search_text)
                  .Append("%' or o.o4 like '%")
                  .Append(search_text)
                  .Append("%' or o.o5 like '%")
                  .Append(search_text)
                  .Append("%' or o.o6 like '%")
                  .Append(search_text)
                  .Append("%' or o.o7 like '%")
                  .Append(search_text)
                  .Append("%' or o.o8 like '%")
                  .Append(search_text)
                  .Append("%' or o.o9 like '%")
                  .Append(search_text)
                  .Append("%' or o.o10 like '%")
                  .Append(search_text)
                  .Append("%' or o.o11 like '%")
                  .Append(search_text)
                  .Append("%' or o.o12 like '%")
                  .Append(search_text)
                  .Append("%' or o.CorrectAns  like '%")
                  .Append(search_text)
                  .Append("%' )");




            flag_checked = 1;

            if (r_Excludestack.Checked)
            {
                sqlcmd.Append(" and Q.qrefNo Not IN (select  qrefno from tblStackData)");
            }

            if (r_search4mstack.Checked)
            {
                sqlcmd.Append(" and Q.qrefNo  IN (select  qrefno from tblStackData)");
            }

            if (r_searchnotused.Checked)
            {
                sqlcmd.Append(" and Q.qrefNo Not IN (select  qrefno from  tblQ where Qused Not In ('','null','0'))");
            }

            if (r_stackedbutnotused.Checked)
            {
                sqlcmd.Append(" and Q.qrefNo  IN (select qrefno from tblStackData where qrefno In(select  qrefno from  tblQ where Qused  In ('','null','0')))");
            }

        }

        if (search_text.Length > 0)
        {
            if (flag_checked == 0)
            {
                flag_checked = 1;
                sqlcmd.Append(" where O.QrefNo like '%" + T_refno.Text.Trim() + "%' ");
            }
            else
            {
                sqlcmd.Append(" and O.QrefNo like '%" + T_refno.Text.Trim() + "%' ");
            }
        }


        //   string en = null;
        //  label6.Invoke(new Action(() => en = c_eventname.Text));
        if (c_eventname.Text != null && c_eventname.Text.Trim() != "")
        {
            if (flag_checked == 0)
            {
                flag_checked = 1;
                sqlcmd.Append(" where en.eventname = '" + c_eventname.Text + "' ");
            }
            else
            {
                sqlcmd.Append(" and en.eventname = '" + c_eventname.Text + "' ");
            }
        }

        //  label6.Invoke(new Action(() => en = c_qtype.Text));
        if (c_qtype.Text != null && c_qtype.Text.Trim() != "")
        {
            if (flag_checked == 0)
            {
                flag_checked = 1;
                sqlcmd.Append(" where Q.QType = '" + c_qtype.Text + "' ");
            }
            else
            {
                sqlcmd.Append(" and Q.QType = '" + c_qtype.Text + "' ");
            }
        }
        //  label6.Invoke(new Action(() => en = c_qtype.Text));
        if (c_level.Text != null && c_level.Text != "")
        {
            if (flag_checked == 0)
            {
                flag_checked = 1;
                sqlcmd.Append(" where Q.QLevel = " + c_level.Text);
            }
            else
            {
                sqlcmd.Append(" and Q.QLevel = " + c_level.Text);
            }
        }

        //   label6.Invoke(new Action(() => en = c_qtype.Text));
        //    Console.WriteLine("Qtype " +  C_category.Text);
        if (C_category.Text != null && C_category.Text != "")
        {
            if (flag_checked == 0)
            {
                flag_checked = 1;
                sqlcmd.Append(" where  C.Cat1 = '" + C_category.Text + "'");
            }
            else
            {
                sqlcmd.Append(" and  C.Cat1 = '" + C_category.Text + "'");
            }

        }
        // label6.Invoke(new Action(() => en =  .Text));
        if (c_subcategory.Text != null && c_subcategory.Text.Trim() != "")
        {
            if (flag_checked == 0)
            {
                flag_checked = 1;
                sqlcmd.Append(" where  C.subCat1 = '" + c_subcategory.Text + "'");
            }
            else
            {
                sqlcmd.Append(" and  C.subCat1 = '" + c_subcategory.Text + "'");
            }
        }

        try
        {
            if (con.State != ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                con.Open();
            }
            cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlcmd.ToString(), con);

            if (dr != null && !dr.IsClosed)
            {
                dr.Close();
            }
            dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();

            while (dr.Read())
            {
                try
                {
                    int f = 0;
                    try
                    {
                        dataGridView1.Rows.Add(dr["qrefno"].ToString(), dr["QType"].ToString(), dr["Qused"].ToString(), dr["CorrectAns"].ToString(), dr["Q"].ToString(), dr["o1"].ToString(), dr["o2"].ToString(), dr["o3"].ToString(), dr["o4"].ToString(), dr["o5"].ToString(), dr["o6"].ToString(), dr["o7"].ToString(), dr["o8"].ToString(), dr["o9"].ToString(), dr["o10"].ToString(), dr["o11"].ToString(), dr["o12"].ToString(), dr["MediaName"].ToString(), dr["MediaType"].ToString(), dr["cat1"].ToString());
                        // label6.Invoke(new Action(() => f = dataGridView1.Rows.Add(dr["qrefno"].ToString(), dr["QType"].ToString(), dr["Qused"].ToString(), dr["CorrectAns"].ToString(), dr["Q"].ToString(), dr["o1"].ToString(), dr["o2"].ToString(), dr["o3"].ToString(), dr["o4"].ToString(), dr["o5"].ToString(), dr["o6"].ToString(), dr["o7"].ToString(), dr["o8"].ToString(), dr["o9"].ToString(), dr["o10"].ToString(), dr["o11"].ToString(), dr["o12"].ToString(), dr["MediaName"].ToString(), dr["MediaType"].ToString(), dr["cat1"].ToString())));
                    }
                    catch (System.InvalidOperationException exe)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                    if (dr["QUsed"].ToString() == "" || dr["QUsed"].ToString() == "0")
                    {

                        //  dataGridView1.Rows[f].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        dataGridView1.Rows[f].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;

                    }

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    dr.Close();

                }


            }
            con.Close();
            l_searchfound.Text = dataGridView1.Rows.Count.ToString();
            //  l_searchfound.Invoke(new Action(() => l_searchfound.Text = dataGridView1.Rows.Count + ""));
            sw.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("Task countUP2 took: " + sw.Elapsed.ToString());
        }
        catch (Exception e1)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e1.ToString());
            con.Close();
            dr.Close();
        }
        // b_search.Enabled = true;
    }
```